# EF Core 3.1 DB First to Code First update old database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The project at the moment is using `Database first` approach, now we are switching to `code first` for various reasons.

using `Scaffold-DbContext` I have generated `DbContext` (we already have, but probably it will be less error prone) from one of dev environments where they are latest changes applied. Removed the copied `.HasConstraintName("");` and `.HasName("");` in `.OnModelCreating()` and I've created the `Initial migration`. So far so good.

The problem comes with updating existing database which is old compared to latest and as well keep the data.
What is the best way to update the database with the migrations?

I've added this in the `Configure()` method under `Startup.cs` to create the database if doesn't exists with the migrations, but not sure  how to update old, existing one which doesn't have migration history table.

```
if (!context.Database.EnsureCreated())
                context.Database.Migrate();
```

Answer (score 1):

One solutions is to  create an initial migration from your old database and put the MigrationId (example : 20200609075705_Initial ) manually into the dbo.EFMigrationHistoryTable.

After that you can add new migrations without any problem .

Comment: So find old database, use old db context to create initial migration and use that migration everytime the app starts if it is not in the migration history table?

Comment: If initial migration not exists in migration history table , then you get error (Table x is already exists) every time you run the application.

Comment: Yes, which migration table will come after `.Migrate()` call, which in turn will throw exception for table already existing. I mean, I can eventually populate the table before the `.Migrate()` but the table won't exist.

Comment: Yes , you're right . Maybe you should create migration table manually too .